# Getting nested subcollections from a document

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

So I have a data structure thats like what is shown below. A user has a collection of months, months have a collection of categories, and categories have a collection of transactions. I am having a hard time getting the data needed from my query. I can get the month as shown below but I am having a hard time figuring out how to get all of the category docs from the month document.

```
user
    email
    name
    --months collection
          month - name, amount
          --categories collection
                category - name, amount <-- I need all of these docs
                --transactions
                    transaction - amount, date
```

Here is where I can get the month but now I need all of the categories from the month so I can loop through them in the html. I think I need the id of the month so I can pull that specific one but from what I understand an Observable doesn't have the id. Is there an easy way of doing this or do I need to rethink my data structure?

```
  monthCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Month>;

  monthName: string;
  totalSpent: number;

  categories: Observable<Category[]>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public navParams: NavParams,
              public alertCtrl: AlertController,
              private firestoreProvider: FirestoreProvider) {

    // Just need the data from the first month
    this.firestoreProvider.getMonthObservable().forEach(doc => {
      this.monthName = doc[0].name.substring(0, 3);
      this.totalSpent = doc[0].totalSpent;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a certain good reason not to, Firestore offers better (compound) query functionality. If you must use Realtime Database, you need to flatten your db architecture as mentioned in their documentation [Structure Your Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data).

> #### Best practices for data structure
>
> - Avoid nesting data
> - Flatten data structures

Comment: I dont think the OP is using the Realtime Database - he appears to already be using Cloud Firestore (which is still beta at this time). It also appears they need the categories from under a specific month - would a compound query help with that?